# Redefine data packet in Kendo UI grid edit popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource, kendo-template

I think this is an advance topic in Kendo UI.
I have a Kendo UI grid and I added a custom edit popup to update the data in the grid.

My data packet like this :

```
{
  fieldOne : "valueOne";
  fieldTwo : "valueTwo";
  fieldThree : [{a : "someValue", b : "someValue"}]
}
```

In edit popup I will edit this data.
But I have a new requirement that add a new value to `fieldThree`.
My new Data packet will look like this...

```
{
 fieldOne : "valueOne";
 fieldTwo : "valueTwo";
 fieldThree : [{a : "someValue", b : "someValue"},{a : "someValue", b : "someValue"}]
}
```

What I have done is I made a custom popup and custom fields for that.
But my question is how I redefine the data packet to above one  ??
In `Kendo UI` it will only update existing values...

Answer (score 0):

The edit event gets fired when you click the button to open the popup and has access to the model.

You may be able to do something like this:

```js
edit: function(e) 
{
  e.model.fieldThree.push({
    a: "someValue",
    b: "someValue"
  });
}
```

That kind of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes,
That is what I want.
Thank you

Comment: So if you do something like:

`$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: viewModel.dataSource,
    columns: [ columns go here],
    edit: ......
});`